# TFS 2010 Configure

Tags: tfs

**TF255356:** The following error occurred when configuring the Team
Foundation databases: Error occurred while validating servicing step
***Add Running User to the TFSADMINROLE for component Install during
Install:*** *Unable to deserialize servicing step data to type
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.AddSqlRoleMemberStepData..
For more information, see the configuration log.*

*Error occurred while validating servicing step Add Running User to the
TFSADMINROLE for component Install during Install: Unable to
deserialize servicing step data to type
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.AddSqlRoleMemberStepData.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem registered in [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588836/tfs-2010-error-during-configuration-phase):

> When I use domain\user and the domain has '&' in it, this error
>   occurs. I don't know what to do anymore.
>
> Error    TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the
>   Team Foundation databases: Error occurred while validating servicing
>   step Add Service Account to Application TFSEXECROLE for component
>   Install during Install: Unable to deserialize servicing step data to
>   type
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.AddSqlRoleMemberStepData..
>   For more information, see the configuration log.

So my guess is that somewhere in your domain, group, service or user name used during installation and configuration of TFS, there is a symbol included that cannot be deserialized correctly. Thinking about symbols like < > & %.

Comment: Another example of a similar bug reported containing an & symbol at:/ http://www.go4answers.com/Example/tfs-2010-error-during-configuration-59292.aspx